# How to find address of a pointer to structure and cast it to void** in CFFI

Tags: c++, python-2.7, python-cffi

My code in C++ is

```
StructureEx* obj; // structure
functionEx((void**)&obj);
```

and my function is

```
int functionEx(void** obj); //calling function
```

I am new to CFFI. So my question is

1. How can I achieve the same in CFFI?
2. How to find the address of a pointer, pointer to structure in CFFI?

I know casting to `void**` can be done by

```
ffi.cast("void*",address)
```

But how can I get that address and pass to the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to declare `arg = ffi.new("void **")` that may be usable.

The following code prints

> <cdata 'void *' NULL>
>
> <cdata 'void *' 0xc173c0>
>
> 7

i.e. first the value of pointer is zero, and after the call the value corresponds to the value set in `functionEx`.

```python
from cffi import FFI

ffi = FFI()
ffi.cdef("""int functionEx(void** obj);""")

C = ffi.dlopen("./foo.so")
print(C)
arg = ffi.new("void **")
print(arg[0])
C.functionEx(arg)
print(arg[0])
ints = ffi.cast("int *", arg[0])
print(ints[7])
```

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int functionEx(void ** obj)
{
    int * arr;
    int i;

    *obj = malloc(sizeof(int) * 8);

    arr = *obj;
    for (i=0; i<8; i++) {
        arr[i] = i;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Hakala for such a clear explanation. 
Can you please explain me whether the particular case stated below works


1) I have allocated memory of a structure for a variable 
struct_object
it shows me 
<cdata 'struct _Name*' 0x00000000002D1D50>
2)  created a void** variable
void_object=cfg_cffi.ffi.new("void**")
3) Assign the memory of struct variable to void** 
void_object[0]=struct_object
4) Now pass void_object[0] for the function stated in the question


The program works without error but returns -1 which is particular failed condition according to the implementation.

Comment: Have you tried passing `void_object` instead of `void_object[0]`?